# Groupby along the axis 1 using a list in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

The following is from "Data Analysis Using Pandas":

> Each grouping key can take many forms, and the keys do not have to be
>   all of the same type:
>
> - A list or array of values that is the same length as the axis being
>     grouped
> - A dict or Series giving a correspondence between the values on the
>     axis being grouped and the group names

I tried the following:

```
df1
         1980   1981    1982    1983    1984    1985    1986
Country                         
Afghanistan 16  39  39  47  71  340 496
Albania 1   0   0   0   0   0   1
Algeria 80  67  71  69  63  44  69
American Samoa  0   1   0   0   0   0   0
Andorra 0   0   0   0   0   0   2

Grouping_keys_along_axis_1
['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3']

df1.groupby(Grouping_keys_along_axis_1, axis = 0).sum()
KeyError: '1'
```

This behavior actually conforms with my understanding of the documentation but it seems to be inconsistent with the fragment I cited in the beginning.

The idea was to to group the first 3 columns together in one group, the next 2 columns in a second group and the last 2 columns in a third group and then apply a summarizing function (here sum()) within each group along the axis = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the following:

```
ga = ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3']

df.groupby(ga, axis=1).sum()
```

Output:

```
                  1    2    3
Country                      
Afghanistan      94  118  836
Albania           1    0    1
Algeria         218  132  113
American Samoa    1    0    0
Andorra           0    0    2
```

Note this works because your ga list length is equal to the length of df.columns index.  So, you using ga (grouping axis) list to determine how to group your columns.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and worked.  Basically I had not prescribed the right axis.